# On partition of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $S \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be positive definite matrix partitioned by
$$S = 
\begin{pmatrix}
S_{11} & S_{12} & S_{13}\\
S_{21} & S_{22} & S_{23}\\
S_{31} & S_{32} & S_{33}\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
S_{(12)} & S_{(12)3}\\
S_{3(12)} & S_{33}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
and
$$S^{-1} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
S^{11} & S^{12} & S^{13}\\
S^{21} & S^{22} & S^{23}\\
S^{31} & S^{32} & S^{33}\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
S^{(12)} & S^{(12)3}\\
S^{3(12)} & S^{33}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
show that:

(1) $(S_{(12)\cdot 3})_{11\cdot 2}= S_{11\cdot(23)}$

(2) $S_{11\cdot 2} = (S^{11\cdot 3})^{-1}$

(3)  $S_{12\cdot 3}(S_{22\cdot 3})^{-1}=-(S^{11})^{-1}S^{12}$

where $S_{11\cdot 2}$ denotes the Schur complement $S_{11\cdot 2}=S_{11}-S_{12}S^{-1}_{22}S_{21}$, etc.

I am not sure if this can be shown by some tricks(since it is possible to do it by very very tedious calculations which I would never recommend for a try)